# How do I return the first item that matches a predicate or the simply first item if none match?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, nullable

I have a list of a very simply entity, which has a nullable DateTime property.
e.g.

```
class MyEntity 
{
    int Id{ get;set; }
    string Category { get; set; }
    DateTime? Date{ get; set ; }
}

var myentities = new List<MyEntity>(..);
```

I'd like to return the `First()` item in the list where *either* the date is the "oldest", or most in the past, or closest to DateTime.Min, whatever way you want to word it, *or* if there are **no** dates set, then get the first item.

This can be done with two statements:

```
var myEntity = myentities
    .Where(me => me.Date != null)
    .OrderBy(me => me.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (myEntity == null)
  myEntity = myentities.First();
```

But is there a way to do this in a single statement?

Comment: In your exampel I can't find nullable DateTime property

Comment: Thats only quick pseudo code to give an idea of the entity without having to write it all out.  Edited to show "DateTime? Date"

Comment: `myentities.Where(me=>me.Date!=null).OrderBy(me=>me.Date).FirstOrDefault() ?? myentities.First()` no single statement, but single line :D

Comment: Thanks, put that as an answer and I'll tick it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
myentities.OrderBy(me=>me.Date.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue)).First();
```

Or you can just fold your collection

```
myentities.Aggregate((a, b) => b.Date.HasValue && (!a.Date.HasValue || a.Date.Value > b.Date.Value) ? b : a);
```

Comment: Like the first option...didn't realise you could specify the value for the ...OrDefault part!

Comment: Given the tick because the first answer is what I actually used.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided in the comments, this should work in your case.

```
var myEntity = myentities
   .OrderBy(me => me.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Since those that are null will always be sorted to the back, if there are ones with dates then they will be chosen otherwise the first one with a null date will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
myentities.Where(d=>d.Date!=null).OrderBy(d=>d.Date).Take(1).Concat(myentities.First()).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

use ?? operator

```
var myEntity = myentities.Where(me => me.Date != null).OrderBy(me => me.Date).FirstOrDefault()
   ?? myentities.First();
```